# RBF neural network python library/implementation

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, rbf

I want to use a Radial Basis Function Neural Network for my thesis.

Is there any library that implements it? And in the negative case, which is the best library to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use gaussian as the nonlinearity and use it in Tensorflow. I guess it is the easiest solution.